# How to load GIF image from drawable folder into ImageView using glide:3.6.0

Tags: android, image, android-drawable, animated-gif, android-glide

I am using glide in my project for the purpose of loading images from the url. But I have another requirement to load GIF image background for my view from drawable folder using glide. I am completely stuck up with the methodology and solutions for loading GIF into my view. I have been struggling with for a couple of days. Kindly please help me with youor solutions to perform loading GIF from drawable using Glid 3.6.0. Thanks in advance. I am posting the piece of code that I am using in my project as follows,

```
Glide.with(LoginActivity.this)
                .load(getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.bg_gif));
                .placeholder(R.drawable.login_bg)
                .crossFade()
                .into(relativeLayout);
```

Note : I have tried using `.asGif()` method to load, but unfortunately it is indicating the error `cannot resolve method asGif()`

Comment: what error? please share.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Thanks for your reply. check my edited question

Answer (score 1):

it may be late now but I load my gif from resources this way:

```
Glide.with(fragment).load(id).asGif().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(img);
```

id is an (int) with the resource file, example:

```
R.drawable.YOURGIFNAME.gif
```

In my case I call glide giving a FragmentActivity, but glide can be called different way check docs https://github.com/bumptech/glide

I found out that the gif wont load if you dont add the:

```
.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet:-

```
        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new 
        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);

        Glide.with(this).load(getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.bg_gif)).
        into(relativeLayout);
```